# How to check if a line casted from one point to another point passes through a mesh?

Tags: 3d, javascript, linear-algebra, three.js

Let's say we have two vectors A and B. Is there a way to use Three.js' Ray or Raycaster classes to cast a line between vector A and vector B and check is it passes through a mesh in the scene? I know from the documentation that both the Ray and Raycaster classes accept origin and direction vectors but I specifically need two points.
Thanks in advance.

[image: example image]

Comment: Presumably you considered computing the offset vector from A to B, then passing A as the origin, (B - A) normalized as the direction, and the length of (B-A) as the far value? Did anything impede this from working in your tests?

Comment: @DMGregory Thank You so much. It's working. I didn't know it could be done so easily.

Answer (score 1):

As @DMGregory answered in the comment it can be done this way:

````js
const a = new Vector3(xa, ya, za);
const b = new Vector3(xb, yb, zb);

const c = b.clone().sub(a);
const far = c.length();

const raycaster = new Raycaster(b, c.normalize(), 0, far);
const intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene);
```
````